# Regex - how to match the text with lookahead around pattern

Tags: regex

The title may by confusing, but what I want to acheive:

I have the string:

```
14:00:01 | some text XXCODE <some text> 
some text 
] 
14:00:02 | some text <some text> XXCODE error 
sometext
]
14:00:03 | some text XXCODE <some text> 
some text
and more text 412432 
]
```

I'd like to match the text which begins with `14:00`, has string `XXCODE`, and ends with first bracket `]` and has anywhere before this bracket text `error`.

So in the example above I'd like to match:

```
14:00:02 | some text <some text> XXCODE error 
sometext
]
```

I've tried with regex: `/14\:00(?=.*?error).*?XXCODE.*?\n]/gs`

but without success because it matches also the first occurence without "error". How to match the above with lookahead only in my matching? Is it possible?

Comment: Try [`^14:00\b[^]]*XXCODE[^]]*error[^]]*]`](https://regex101.com/r/Tjl3ya/2)

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, it doesn't work, please see: https://regex101.com/r/A2ddmd/1/

Comment: I don't see any `14:30` in your input string.

Comment: It does, see https://regex101.com/r/A2ddmd/2. You did not set the multiline modifier.

Comment: Ah, yes, multiline, perfect!

Comment: Is there any chances for `error` to occur before `XXCODE`?

Comment: @revo, sorry, I've updated question, with 14:00

Comment: @revo, yes, it is possible that error will occur before XCODE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^14:00\b[^]]*XXCODE[^]]*error[^]]*]
```

In order to match at the start of each *line* make sure the multiline flag is passed to the regex compiler (unless you are using it in a text editor like Notepad++, line based tools like `sed` or Ruby where `^` already matches the start of a line).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A2ddmd/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (when used with the multiline modifier)
- `14:00\b` - a `14:00` value as a whole word
- `[^]]*` - 0+ chars other than `]`
- `XXCODE` - a literal `XXCODE` substring
- `[^]]*` - 0+ chars other than `]`
- `error` - a literal `error` substring
- `[^]]*` - 0+ chars other than `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

If the last closing `]` must reside on a separate line, you may use

```
^14:00\b[^]]*XXCODE[^]]*error.*\r?\n(?:(?!]$).*\r?\n)*]$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A2ddmd/4)

Here, the `.*\r?\n(?:(?!]$).*\r?\n)*]$` part is of interest:

- `.*\r?\n` - matches the rest of the first line
- `(?:(?!]$).*\r?\n)*` - matches 0+ sequences of:

  - `(?!]$)` - there can't be `]` at the end of the line right after the beginning of the new line
  - `.*\r?\n` - the rest of the line
- `]$` - matches `]` at the end of the line.

If the `error` may come before `XXCODE`, use an alternation:

```
^14:00\b[^]]*(?:XXCODE[^]]*error|error[^]]*XXCODE)[^]]*]
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A2ddmd/3)

Comment: Wiktor, could you advise if I would like to match as above but to first bracket in new line?

Comment: @robson Do you mean there may be `]` between `error` and closing `]`?

Comment: Yes, I know I didn't specify that, but now I see I need this. There may be some `[]` but the closing `]` should be in new line - so `^]`

Answer (score 1):

Since `error` may occur before `XXCODE` you will need lookarounds to look but not consume:

```
^14:00(?=[^]]*error)[^]]*XXCODE[^]]*\]
```

**RegEx Breakdown**:

```
^14:00  # Match lines beginning with 14:00
(?= # Construct a positive lookahead
    [^]]*error # That looks for `error` wherever possible before `]`
)   # End of lookahead
[^]]*XXCODE[^]]*\] # Match rest up to a `]` should include `XXCODE`
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dK7HDq/2)